# Can sed do this?

Tags: bash, sed

(I use BSD Sed.)

This bash script:

```
sed -E -f parsefile < parsewords.d
```

With this command file:

```
# Delete everything before BEGIN RTL and after END RTL
\?/\* BEGIN RTL \*/?,\?/\* END RTL \*/?!d   

# Delete comments unless they begin with /*!
s?/\*[^!].*\*/??g       

# Delete blank lines
/^[     ]*$/d

# Break line into words
s/[^A-Za-z0-9_]+/ /g 

# Remove leading and trailing spaces and tabs
s/^[    ]*(.*)[     ]*$/\1/
```

With this input file:

```
any stuff
/* BEGIN RTL */

/*! INPUTS: a  b c d ph1   */ /* Comment */
x = a && b || c && d;

    y = x ? a : b;  /* hello */
z = ph1 ? x : z;
  w = c || x || (z || d);
/* END RTL */
```

Produces this result:

```
INPUTS a b c d ph1 
x a b c d 
y x a b 
z ph1 x z 
w c x z d
```

That's fine so far but what I'd really like to have is something like this:

```
x = a && b || c && d; x a b c d
y = x ? a : b; y x a b
z = ph1 ? x : z; z ph1 x z
w = c || x || (z || d); w c x z d
```

so that the original line is retained along with the mods that the script is making.

Is this possible with sed or should I use something else.  (Any other comments are welcome too.)

EDIT: This is not a parsing question.  It is about retaining the original input line along with sed modifications.

Comment: A: What is a lexer?<br> Q: What should I use to parse this. See also, yacc, bison, etc.

Comment: @Nathan: But the parsing is working fine.  The only problem is retaining the original input line.

Comment: if parsing is not required, maybe using awk instead of sed can help to solve your task.

Comment: @grok12: What I meant to imply is that of course sed can do this for some specific input, but you're evidently parsing C code which can be arbitrarily complex: To solve the real-world problem you should look at a parser/lexer.

Comment: @Nathan: I should have pointed out that I am the only user for this script and the C code will be written with limitations due to other factors so this type of simple parsing will work fine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A solution using 'sed'.

Input file (infile):

```
any stuff
/* BEGIN RTL */

/*! INPUTS: a  b c d ph1   */ /* Comment */
x = a && b || c && d;

    y = x ? a : b;  /* hello */
z = ph1 ? x : z;
  w = c || x || (z || d);
/* END RTL */
```

'Sed' program (script.sed):

```
# Delete everything before BEGIN RTL and after END RTL
\?/\* BEGIN RTL \*/?,\?/\* END RTL \*/?!d   

# Delete comments unless they begin with /*!
s?/\*[^!].*\*/??g       

# Delete blank lines
/^[     ]*$/d

# Copy current line in hold space.
h

# Break line into words
s/[^A-Za-z0-9_]+/ /g 

# Join both lines with a ';'.
H ; g ; s/\n/ / ; s/;\s+/; /

# Remove leading and trailing spaces and tabs
s/^[    ]*(.*)[     ]*$/\1/
```

Execution:

```
$ sed -E -f script.sed infile
```

Output (I don't understand the line with the 'INPUTS' word, but change the script to adapt it):

```
/*! INPUTS: a  b c d ph1   */   INPUTS a b c d ph1 
x = a && b || c && d; x a b c d 
y = x ? a : b; y x a b 
z = ph1 ? x : z; z ph1 x z 
w = c || x || (z || d); w c x z d
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd say using sed for this kind of task will prove to be difficult.

Maybe you need to look into parsing/lexing?